# Is it possible in TFS\VSTS to identify releases where the deployment approval was overridden?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

In TFS / VSTS administrators can approve release deployment even though they are not specified as approvers. They can use the Override option to approve the release.

I'm trying to determine whether we can report on this type of activity. I anticipate we will be asked (eg. by our audit / security people) to identify releases which were not approved by the usual approvers.

I've checked the deployment and approval history using the Rest API and the releases are all marked as Approved. It doesn't seem to distinguish between normal approvals and ones where an override was used.

We are currently using TFS 2017.1 but I suspect the question also applies to later versions and VSTS.

[ Update ]

This is the standard dialog showing the normal approver view ...

[Normal Approval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvRYn.png)

This is what a TFS Admin (not in the approver group) gets ...

[Override approval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyaOb.png)

Clicking on override shows the normal dialog and approval follows. This is normal TFS behaviour and I just want to report on when the override feature is used.

Comment: Both for VSTS and TFS, only the specified users in release definition can approval release deployment. Even for the administrators, if they are not specified in the approvers list, they can not approve the deployment.

Comment: If you have "Administer Release Permissions" permission you can approve the deployment of a release, even if you are not specifically listed as an approver. You get an "Override" option on the deployment approval dialog. Members of Release Administrators get this permission, and it can be given to other groups or users.

Comment: It should not happen. In order to get details, can you show related scree shots here (the approvers list in release definition and the administrator who does not specify in approvers list but can approve deployment)?

Comment: Details added. It's normal behavior in TFS to allow admin override on deployments. I just want to be able to report when it has happened.

Comment: I added an answer for idenfiy whether a release approval is overridden, and you can have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the override of a release approval, it’s actually for **another user approval the deployment on behalf of specified approval**.

And there are multiple options you can identify whether a release approval is overridden.

#### Option 1: Check in the release log

You can check the release log -> click the approval icon -> then you can find who approval the deployment.

[image]

#### Option 2: Check by REST API

Or you can use [Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/get%20release?view=vsts-rest-4.1) REST API:

```
GET https://{account}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/Git2/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=4.1-preview.6
```

Then you can get the detail information under `preDeployApprovals`. If the user in `approver` different from the user in `approvedBy`, then the approval is overridden.

[image]

Comment: I think the API provides the best way to approach it. In our case the approver will be a group and the approvedBy will be an individual who may or may not be in the group. We can include a step in the deployment automation to check whether the approver is in the group or not and take appropriate action if not.

It would be easier to identify, though, if there was a value in the data that recorded an override action. Maybe they will add that in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Marked as answer.